# How Can I use filter for remove particular event?

Tags: ios, swift

How Can I replace below functionality with the filter?

```
 for index in 0..<self.array.count {
            let event = self.array[index]
            if event?.label == event1?.label{
                self.array.remove(at: index)
                break
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let arr = array.filter{ $0.label != event1?.label  }
```

Comment: It is removing all elements

Comment: may be because of optional , in case that **event1?.label** is nil  and label of rhs is also nil , Do you really have to use ? , you can provide other value when nil with **??**